# C++: &*A is not equivalent to A for array declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, dereference

The C standard 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators (3) says:

> "The unary & operator returns the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue."

---

> "83) Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), and &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2)). It is always true that if E is a function designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary & operator, *&E is a function designator or an lvalue equal to E. If *P is an lvalue and T is the name of an object pointer type, *(T)P is an lvalue that has a type compatible with that to which T points."

So if I understand well, `&*E` is behave as if we would delete `&*`. However,

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    float A[2];
    printf( "name: %s\n", typeid( &*A ).name());
    printf( "name: %s\n", typeid( A ).name());
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

will give:

```
name: Pf
name: A2_f
```

So they aren't the same.

What is wrong? What is I'm misunderstanding? I would appreciate your help,
Thanks.

Comment: I used to believe that for compatibility reasons they dont change the behaviour of the expressions. So the quotes probably are out-of-date?

Comment: Well, since C doesn't have typeid, there's no compatibility issue here.

Comment: Please understand that C++ and C are different languages with different standards. The question currently doesn't make sense at all because it's tagged C++ and contains a reference to the C standard.

Comment: Try searching for "&*" in the **C++** standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

Comment: Also note that the `name()` member function should not be relied upon, because its result is entirely implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks your help, i'm okey now.

Comment: If you would like to update the question to be C, not C++, [you could use `sizeof` instead of `typeid`](http://ideone.com/SNdTeS). This would illustrate the problem in the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These aren't the same.

The `&*A` gives you the address of the 1st element in the `A` array as a decayed pointer `float*`, and `A` is a particular array type as declared with `float A[2]`.

Answer (score 5):

[πάντα ῥεῖ's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707480/2069064) answer explains why `&*A` and `A` are different for the simple case when `A` is an array.

But more generally, since C++ allows overloading of `operator*` and `operator&`, the two could be widely different. For a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<int> p`, `&*p` is an `int*`, which isn't even close to the same type as `p`.

Answer (score 4):

In case of [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

> Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer conversions are not performed.

So, `&*A` and `A` are not same in this case. `A` will not decay to pointer to its first element in `typeid( A ).name()`.

The same behavior can be seen with `sizeof` operator

```
int main()
{
    float A[10];
    printf( "name: %zu\n", sizeof( &*A )); // &*A --> float * type
    printf( "name: %zu\n", sizeof( A ));   // A   --> float[10] type
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
name: 8
name: 40
```